# When to use Stack and when to use OverlayEntry

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a typeahead and initially started with a Stack, but [was running into problems with it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55465432/absolutely-position-one-widget-with-a-stack) I eventually found a [tutorial](https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9) that uses OverlayEntry to achieve the same affect. I'm running into problems with removing the OverlayEntry more than once in my instance though. Someone had commented in my original question to see how the `material/dropdown.dart` works. I took a look and it uses a stack.

How do I know when to use a Stack and when to use an OverlayEntry?

Answer (score 0):

An `OverlayEntry` apparently *is* a `Stack`, so if you can get what you want done with Stack, I'd start with that for most flexibility.